# Set only refers to a type but it is being used as a value - WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings

I have an Angular 4 project powered with webpack.
I used TypeScript in the project and I'm using WebStorm as an IDE.

In my code, I use `Set` without problem.

I want to use `Set` as well in my unit test to return a value from a mocked function.

When I try to use `new Set(['A', 'B'])`, I see an error in WebStorm:

> Set only refers to a type but it is being used as a value

This error is coming from TSLint (I assume) but I can't see the same error in Iterm when I run the TSLint class manually (so I assume it is WebStorm that is not recognizing Set).

In WebStorm configuration, TSLint is enable and look at tsconfig.json, this is the `compilerOptions` part of tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ],
  },
}
```

Any idea why WebStorm is complaining (only inside unit test)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, not sure if it's the good one but I installed @types/es6-collections

```
npm install --save-dev @types/es6-collections
```

And add it in tsconfig.json:

```
"types": [
      "es6-collections",
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ],
```

That removes the error from webstorm for me

Comment: that might be the solution, but also check what level of JS you are compiling to. Set is part of the ES6 standard and you might not get it in all browsers if you compile to ES5.

Comment: I'm compiling to es6 ("target": "es6"), so I was surprised to see this error in the first place

Comment: hm, do you have lib-es6 added to your libs in compiler config?

Comment: @toskv: Yes I do, I have ES6, ES2017 and DOM in libs